# Use middleware only for json server specific routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

How can I use a middleware ONLY FOR my json-server specific routes? In the [json-server docs](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#access-control-example), I can see the following instructions:

```
const jsonServerRouter = jsonServer.router('mock-server/db.json')


server.use(customMiddleware)
server.use(jsonServerRouter) // customMiddleware should be executed ONLY FOR this jsonServerRouter

/*
Problem is here, customMiddleware has already been executed,
so following routes will use the middleware too
*/
server.use(otherRoutes)
```

What I've tried:

```
// This syntax is similar to the previous code. So it doesnt work
server.use(customMiddleware, jsonServerRouter)
```

```
// Passing the middleware to the 'router' function doesnt work
const jsonServerRouter = jsonServer.router('mock-server/db.json', customMiddleware)
```

Comment: then just put it inside `use()`? Like `server.use(customMiddleware, jsonServerRouter)`

Comment: Thats similar to the code in the question. Already tried :(

Comment: in your `customMiddleware`, check `req.path` and then run it if it's the route, else call `next()`

Comment: @traynor That would be an option... but requires changing the `path` variable if endpoints paths change in the future. A violation of 'dont repeat yourself (DRY)' good practice IMO. But seems like theres not other way :(

Comment: isn't it possible by simply changing the order i.e. define `otherRoutes` first and then register middleware?